# Best way to save large data to SQL server using Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

I have a buffer data which is approximately 320MB. I am trying to save it into SQL server table from node js.

What is the best way I can do this? When I try to insert the buffer data directly I am getting `Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters`.

What can I do to save it?

This is my buffer data

```
<Buffer 53 6f 75 72 63 65 53 63 68 65 6d 61 2c 43 6f 75 6e 74 72 79 4e 61 6d 65 2c 49 44 2c 41 4d 54 5f 45 58 43 4c 5f 54 41 58 2c 41 4d 54 5f 49 4e 43 4c 5f ... 340629006 more bytes>
```

I am trying to save this data to database using sequelize as below

```
const DBMODEL = require("../../../models/SaveBufferData")

module.exports = async (req, res) => {

try{
var bufdata = req.file.buffer;

 var fdata = fs.writeFile('files/uploaded_files/' + req.body.fileName, bufdata, "utf8", function (err) {
          console.log('errrrr',err)
          stream = fs.createReadStream('files/uploaded_files/' + req.body.fileName);
          
        // Read and display the file data on console
        stream.on('data', function (chunk) {
            console.log(chunk);
        });
        stream.on('end', function(){
          console.log('stream ended')
      })
      
      stream.on('open', function(){
          console.log('File opened')
      });
        })
var response = await DBMODEL.SaveBufferData(req.body.fileId, bufdata);

} catch (error) {
   console.log('errorerror',error)
   res.status(500).json(ResponseManager(false, error.message));
 }
```

I ended up with the  below error

```
node:buffer:669
slice: (buf, start, end) => buf.hexSlice(start, end),
                                ^

Error: Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters
    at Object.slice (node:buffer:669:37)
    at Buffer.toString (node:buffer:811:14)
    at BLOB._stringify (C:\IWA-BACKEND\PRIMS-local\PRIMS - Iwa\BACKEND\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\data-types.js:423:23)
    at BLOB.stringify (C:\IWA-BACKEND\PRIMS-local\PRIMS - Iwa\BACKEND\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\data-types.js:22:19)
    at escape (C:\IWA-BACKEND\PRIMS-local\PRIMS - Iwa\BACKEND\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\sql-string.js:40:48)
    at C:\IWA-BACKEND\PRIMS-local\PRIMS - Iwa\BACKEND\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\sql-string.js:101:14
    at String.replace (<anonymous>)
    at Object.formatNamedParameters (C:\IWA-BACKEND\PRIMS-local\PRIMS - Iwa\BACKEND\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\sql-string.js:96:14)
    at Object.formatNamedParameters (C:\IWA-BACKEND\PRIMS-local\PRIMS - Iwa\BACKEND\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\utils.js:112:20)
    at Sequelize.query (C:\IWA-BACKEND\PRIMS-local\PRIMS - Iwa\BACKEND\node_modules\sequelize\dist\lib\sequelize.js:283:21) {
  code: 'ERR_STRING_TOO_LONG'
}
```

Comment: Did you try searching for "Cannot create a string longer than 0x1fffffe8 characters" and follow up on those answers?

Comment: Where is your data? Which format has the data? complete your question.

Comment: @MeyssamToluie I added my data and the code I tried in the question now.

Comment: @Andy Yes, but I didnt find a solution

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the call-stack, this is what I diagnose is happening :

1. You are passing a file as a buffer (from multer I guess) to the sequelize node module
2. sequelize node module is calling Blob.stringify

step 2) is where you are probably hitting node string length upper limits

Try the following to test this hypothesis

-> try this endpoint with a file of a smaller size and keep incrementing the size of the said file ,

if this endpoint succeeds for smaller file sizes and fails after a certain file size is reached , we are can mention with high probability that the file to buffer to string conversion is the issue (as in we are hitting the ceiling of allowed size of string by either the node process or the system memory)

Comment: yes I tried with small files. It is working fine

Comment: If it is working with small files then the issue is the way the solution is designed, 
the issue here is the transport of data in the file before being saved to sql, the file is loaded onto buffer (system memory) and then saved on the database,

Ideally file handling should not be done on memory, multer allows you to use storage(disk) , try using storage with multer instead of memory and then you can write your logic in a manner that reads the file in chunks and "updates" the sql column with the contents, 

ideally use a blob storage to save files

Comment: I have edited my question and added a piece of code. I am trying to chunk the data and save the chunks in database. But I am not sure that can I combine these chunks later and get the original data back?

Comment: It depends(assuming original data back means fetching from db gives the same output as the file) largely on multiple factors like:

1) are you always going to deal with utf-8 encoded data in files?
2) is the way you are reading chunks sync or async ? (data will have to be read in a sync manner because the sequence of data matters in your context)

Comment: The overarching comment remains:
File contents are usually not advised to be stored onto Relational database columns, ideally we use blob storage services for this, my answers to your question assume that using blob storage is not an option.

Comment: I was not using multer because it was not giving the data in the sequence. But I am unaware that even createReadstream will also not read the data in sequence? if so what can I do to save the data into database?

Comment: I was thinking that I can save the chunks into DB and fetch them back